# Since Bootstrap 4 alpha 3 col push pull is not working but working on alpha 1 & 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Push and Pull for columns is working on alpha 1 & 2
but I discover using alpha 3 to 6 it is not working.

I included [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uouvmybm/11/).

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-push-4">2</div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-pull-4">1</div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 alpha 3, the push/pull class names changed..

from `col-{tier}-push-{size}` to `push-{tier}-{size}`
from `col-{tier}-pull-{size}` to `pull-{tier}-{size}`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 push-md-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 pull-md-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">3</div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/DvQNHOoFX8